# Una ayudita para tags y animators porfa unity

Tags: c#, unity2d

necesito una ayuda para esto

```
    public Animator animatorT;

    //enter
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        animatorT.SetBool("idle", false);
        animatorT.SetBool("wait", false);
    }
```

esto es lo que "llevo" avanzado, la cuestión es que quiero que todos los objetos que tengan este animator por medio de un tag se active el animator

si necesitan mas detalle en comentario y yo intentare guiar porfa

-llevo 4 días con esto ayuda

Comment: ¿Que has investigado? ¿Qué haces con el `OnTrigger`? Sobre los 4 días, hay personas en situaciones peores. Esos sí que necesitan ayuda.

Comment: no niego que soy novato, para mi 4 dias es mucho aun, el ontrigger es para las coliciones, no encontre mucho la verdad, solo encontre "findobjectswithtag"

Comment: Siendo que no explicas demasiado, dentro de una función que se llame frecuentemente como `Update` o dónde te creas adecuado puedes poner un if verificando si el tag es el que quieres. Más o menos como en [el ejemplo de la documentación](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-tag.html).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una lista de GameObjects activos etiquetados con tu tag. por ejemplo:

```
 GameObject[] objectWithAnimation;
 objectWithAnimation =GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TuTag");
 foreach (GameObject anim in objectWithAnimation ) {
       anim.Animation.Play()
 }
```